# Qt Get the amount of up time for current application

Tags: c++, qt, time

Is there a way in qt to get the up time of the application as well as the up time for the system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use something similar to `/proc/uptime` on Linux systems.  The file has two floating point numbers which are used to report the uptime, idle time, etc.  Your program could write a similar file at `/proc/(program-pid)/uptime`.  For Linux systems, that is.

Comment: @vpit3833 You can't write new files at `/proc/anything`

Comment: @Ken might be.  But on Linux systems, Emacs somehow writes a whole `/proc/(emacs-pid)/` directory and uptime.el for example reads this directory to report Emacs' uptime.  I run Emacs as normal user, not as root, so I don't get any special privileges there.  I have not read the code base of Emacs, so I don't know how it does this.

Comment: @Pratik `/proc/uptime` contains two floating point numbers which get updated periodically.  The command `uptime` parses this file to report its output.  I was suggesting a similar file at `/proc/pid/uptime` be written and parsed as needed.  As noted in the previous comment, I don't know how it is done, otherwise I would have written it in an answer with full how to.

Comment: @vpit3833: The purpose of the `/proc` file system is to make information about system processes available as readable files. All of the files and directories in `/proc` are created by the kernel. Only certain files can be written to, and you can't create your own. Emacs just reads the appropriate field from `/proc/(emacs pid)/stat`. See http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlproc.html

Comment: @Ken thank you for reminding me.  I was wrong, yes, the kernel writes to /proc and other processes read from there.  /proc/pid is how the kernel looks at a process.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qelapsedtimer.html) class from Qt 4.7 to get uptime for your app. This class will use monotonic clocks if it can.

Just create an instance, and call `start` on it at the start of your program. From then on, you can get the number of milliseconds your program has been running (or more precisely, since the call to `start`) by calling

```
myElapsedTimer.elapsed()
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows` you can simply calculate by calling `Winapi` function to get process start `datetime`.

More information you can find at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ProcessTime.aspx

Comment: I suppose that I could store the current date time when the program starts to get the current up time for the application but what about system up time?

Comment: @You might need to be careful with that method - 'wall clock' time can change, e.g. by the user or time servers etc.

Comment: @Thomas On Win you can use the api 'GetTickCount' https://stackoverflow.com/a/46885779/260242

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use the [`times`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) system call to tell you elapsed processor time. This will not count the time your program has been idle waiting for input, or blocked waiting for input, or the time that it's been preempted by other programs also running on the system. (Therefore, this makes it very good for benchmarks.)