# get Computer working time using winAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, system, uptime

I want to get my computer's working time since when I pushed the power button to start my PC using windows APIs. So it is not the system's current time.
For example I want to calculate how many seconds passed since windows started.

There is a function `DWORD WINAPI GetTickCount(void);`. Is that the one?

My idea is that if we could get bios information like uptime of the machine from ram or rom?

Comment: "But I am not sure if it is fit for this." Then make it sure by consulting the documentation: "The return value is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx
Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: No, this doesn't meet your requirements. [GetTickCount64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411.aspx), on the other hand, does. Or might, anyway. Apparently everyone seems to be hooked on any system's power button initiating a shutdown. It doesn't on my system. And there are systems without a power button altogether. So what do you really need?

Comment: "pushed the power button" just doesn't mean anything.  It has been a long, long time since the power button actually turned the power on/off or forced the OS to reboot.  You'll have to tell us why this is important and what you intend to do with the information, given that is so very rarely useful information.  Well, never.

Comment: Well it is homework of my system programming lesson. :)

Comment: This is the third version of your question now (counting comments), that has a third, different answer. This is not why Stack Overflow is successful. Please ask a real, answerable question, and don't change a question once you have received an answer, when that change invalidates the answer.

Comment: I'm sure the homework isn't: Ask Stack Overflow how to do it. And No, the BIOS has a clock chip running on a battery and doesn't care if the computer is on or off. That clock runs anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable . The reason was asked and I just answered. That is not other version of the question. There is only one existing question. Please do not troll here by saying irrelevant things but suggesting any idea if you have any.

Comment: @BoPersson. Exactly . Actually this was the point. The clock goes on ticking although PC suspending or sleeping.  How to convert that tick count to genuine time. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You have been asking for different things on three occasions. This question is probably not going to be salvageable, and is best closed off. Unless you fix what's wrong with it. Start by taking the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: There is also the last boot up time which the operating system saves. I think starting with Windows 8, the shutdown option is hybrid shutdown, and not a full shutdown. The boot up time is reset only by restart or startup after full shutdown. This information is not much more useful that `GetTickCount64`

Answer (score 2):

The [GetTickCount64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411.aspx) is documented as:

> Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.

That is what is commonly referred as a system's uptime. It's unclear, what the power button has to do with this, though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think misunderstood. Power button doesnt need to do anything but starting the bios and system as normal. And I am just looking for a way to calculate how much time passed since the first starting o the machine.. I am using suspending option. And when I commended 'uptime' it shows the system's working time. But I want to see since the first clicking to power button.

Comment: @EyüpAkay: If you need the cumulative system uptime (i.e. all system uptime added together), you need to make that clear. This is not something that can be inferred from your question as asked.

Comment: Thank you considerations. I edited the question.